# How to copy a list to a list with different but compatible generic type?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to copy elements from a list of a generic type (ShipModule) to another list of a different, but compatible type (IRepairable).

```
    List<ShipModule> modules = new List<ShipModule>();
    // Add some modules...

    List<IRepairable> repairables;
    repairables = new List<IRepairable>();

    // This is an error:
    repairables.AddRange(modules);

    // So is this:
    repairables = new List<IRepairable>(modules);

    // This is okay:
    foreach(ShipModule module in modules) {
        repairables.Add(module);
    }
```

ShipModule implements IRepairable, so all the elements can be safely added, but I can't use the copy constructor or AddRange. Why?

Comment: `var repairables = modules.OfType<IRepairable>().ToList()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If yo'ure using .NET 3.5, you can use [Enumerable.Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
repairables = new List<IRepairable>(modules.Cast<IRepairable>());
```

Note that your versions do work in C#4/.NET 4 and later, as `IEnumerable<T>` became `IEnumerable<out T>`, and C# 4 supports [covariance in generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @paqogomez Yes, added, as well as pointed out that this does work in C# 4+

Answer (score 0):

You're using a version of C# before C# 4.0 when covariance was added.  If you switch to C# 4.0+ then you are able to leverage covariance, in particular here, `IEnumerable<T>` will become covariant, allowing you to treat an `IEnumerable<ShipModule>` as if it were an `IEnumerable<IRepairable>`.